# Encoding problem with the batch ipconfig command

Tags: batch-file, encoding, command-line, character-encoding, export

My goal is to export some commands into a txt file and the keep the accent (é, è, î, etc).

I have two different commands :

```
CHCP 65001
ipconfig /all 1>>file.txt
```

`CHCP 65001` is supposed to change the encoding to UTF-8 (so the accent are supposed to work).

But the second one, `ipconfig /all` does not work at all (all of the accents are replaced with strange characters) and when I convert the file to UTF-8 within notepad++ it does not work either (there is still strange characters like x93, x85, ...).

What I got (just an extract) :

```
DHCP activ‚. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Non
Configuration automatique activ‚e. . . : Oui
Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: x.x.x.x(pr‚f‚r‚) 
Masque de sous-r‚seau. . . .ÿ. . . . . : x.x.x.x
Passerelle par d‚faut. . . .ÿ. . . . . : x.x.x.x
```

What I want :

```
DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Non
Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui
Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: x.x.x.x(préféré) 
Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : x.x.x.x
Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : x.x.x.x
```

I also tried to export an echo in the txt file before, to use powershell to execute the command (`powershell "my command" 1>>file.txt`). I also tried to do it from the command line AND if I redirect the command to a txt file and then write `type file.txt` everything is fine. BUT when I open the file.txt after that, the bugged characters are back T_T. but nothing worked...

**How do I export my ipconfig command with the accents ?**

Feel free to ask any questions for more informations, I'll try to answer you.

PS : my computer is on french so there is accents litteraly EVERYWHERE
(and sorry for my bad english)

**EDIT :** I just deleted the example with the `<command1>` because it was useless and something completely different from my problem so I'm trying with just the 2 commands CHCP and ipconfig.

Comment: Does the `ipconfig` command work correctly if the `<command1>` line is removed? I suspect that whatever that command is, it's breaking your encoding.

Comment: not at all @SomethingDark ... Sorry I forgot to say it but i also tried to just change the encoding and redirect the output of my command directly (and also without changing the encoding). (I just edited the post to add it)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share what is `<command1>` as well as  what you get (with _strange characters_) and what you expect. Post a hexadecimal dump of your `file.txt` if possible.

Comment: @JosefZ I just made the edits and I'm sorry but my `<command1>` was just to explain that the redirection work correctly with some commands but not with `ipconfig`. And I don't understand how to make the hexadecimal dump (I searched a bit on internet but it looks like I can't do it without installing something else)...

Comment: Why do you think you need to use codepage 65001? or more precisely why do you think you need to use Unicode (UTF-8)? What happens if you use, for instance, codepage 850, 1252, or if it's available 28591? I would also like to know the result when you use `1>` instead of `1>>`.

Comment: Well done. You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'‚ÿ'.encode('cp1252').decode('cp850')` gives `é\xa0` (the latter means `é` (U+00E9,  *Latin Small Letter E With Acute*) and ` ` (U+00A0,  *No-Break Space*). I doubt that `ipconfig.exe` is Unicode aware tool. Maybe from `cmd /U`?

Comment: @Compo I was thinking that CHCP will also change the encoding of the redirected outputs (but it looks like its not the case). The codepages you asked me to tried does not change anything, and using 1> or 1>> too.

Comment: I didn't ask or suggest that they may fix something. My question was why you think 65001, (similar to UTF-8) is what you need for the standard French language character set, when all three of the codepages I suggested covers exactly those.

Comment: @JosefZ I tried `cmd /u /c ipconfig /all 1>file.txt` and it does not solve my problem (same strange characters as before). Maybe I made a mistake in the syntax I rarely use it.

Comment: @Compo because the 850 does not work for me (with another command, in another script) and also because the 65001 was the first one I found when I tried to fix my older problem (I never saw the 1252 and the 28591). So it's completely random if you ask xD

Comment: The default code page for French computers is... Open a Command Prompt window, type ```mode con cp``` and press the `[ENTER]` key, to find out what yours is!

Comment: @Compo you're right is says 850 but when I try to redirect it does'nt work with powercfg. (I'll stop detailling this because it works with UTF-8 and it's supposed to work on as many different server as possible and also because we're leaving the first topic of this post). Thanks for the infos :)

Comment: [If you need full unicode support use PowerShell. There is still VERY limited support for unicode in the CMD shell, piping, **redirection and most commands are still ANSI only**…](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html).

Comment: I always upvote new users that improve their question per requests from comments. Well done^2!  ... But ... use your `tags` more wisely. I didn't realize until near the end of the comments that yours was basically an MS Windows question (althought `CHCP` should have made that obvious). ... While batch-file was a clue that you are in MS land, desite the tag definition, batch-file has a general meeting that roughly equals *nix shell script (not your fault!). So ..  use an Windows tag for Windows questions in the future. Good luck!